# How to add Mule header using Interceptor?

Tags: header, namespaces, mule, cxf, interceptor

Hi I have a soap request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns2:TrackRequest xmlns:ns4="namespace4" xmlns:ns3="namespace3" xmlns:ns2="namespace2" xmlns="namespace1">
        <Request>
            <RequestOption>BB</RequestOption>
        </Request>
        <ns2:InquiryNumber>AA</ns2:InquiryNumber>
    </ns2:TrackRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

I want it in this way

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <ns3:MYSecurity xmlns:ns3="namespace3">
        <ns3:UsernameToken>
            <ns3:Username>5</ns3:Username>
            <ns3:Password>N</ns3:Password>
        </ns3:UsernameToken>
        <ns3:ServiceAccessToken>
            <ns3:AccessLicenseNumber>AC</ns3:AccessLicenseNumber>
        </ns3:ServiceAccessToken>
    </ns3:MYSecurity>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Body>
    <ns2:TrackRequest xmlns:ns4="namespac4" xmlns:ns3="namespace3" xmlns:ns2="namespace2" xmlns="namespace1">
        <Request>
            <RequestOption>BB</RequestOption>
        </Request>
        <ns2:InquiryNumber>AA</ns2:InquiryNumber>
    </ns2:TrackRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

How can I do it using mule SOAP CXF component? can we use

```
public class SecurityHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
```

//java code
}

class file to do this task using Java? if can how is that? its need to be  type after adding header.

Comment: Have you tried using the log4j2.xml logging configuration? <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" level="ALL" />, just add the package of  CXF.

Comment: Nope.. How to do that?

Comment: What version of mule are you using?

Comment: I am using mule 3.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor then modify the SOAPMessage header.

Check this link for sample implementation of writing to SOAPMessage header: https://www.classle.net/#!/classle/content-page/intercepting-soap-message/

Answer (score 0):

We can use org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor and override the handleMessage(SoapMessage message)